# Syntax error: "integer expression expected"

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am using below script

```
x=5.44
p=0
temp=$(printf "%.*f\n" $p $x)
echo $temp
if [ temp -gt 0 ]
  then
  echo "inside"
fi
```

and I am getting below output with error.

```
5
./temp.sh: line 6: [: temp: integer expression expected
```

Comment: Bash’s built-in `printf` has a `-v` option to store the result in a shell variable to avoid the need for command substitution like this. `printf -v temp ...` is equivalent to `temp=$(printf ...)` but carries much less overhead than the latter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `$` for the shell to expand temp (As your script is written you are trying to compare the literal string `temp` to the integer `0`).  You also should quote it:

```
x=5.44
p=0
temp=$(printf "%.*f\n" $p $x)
echo "$temp"
if [ "$temp" -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "inside"
fi
```

---

If you are using bash a better way to do it would be using bash arithmetic expression like so:

```
x=5.44
p=0
temp=$(printf "%.*f\n" $p $x)
echo "$temp"
if ((temp>0)); then
  echo "inside"
fi
```

Inside of the arithmetic expression `((…))` you do not need a `$` for expansion and you cannot quote.